# Flink recovery order

Tags: apache-flink

I want to know some details about the recovery phase of flink. The operators independently load the state and then recover? Or in the order of the operator of the topology, first load the state from the source in order, and then recover?

Answer (score 1):

The recovery of state happens independently once an operator has been deployed. The deployment of streaming programs happens in topological order but Flink does not wait until a deployed operator has recovered its state. Instead, it will try to eagerly deploy consumers once it knows where the producers will be deployed to.